# Как в go получить код ошибки а не ее описание?

Tags: golang, обработка-ошибок

Как в go получить код ошибки а не ее описание? В дебагере у ошибки есть поле Code, но я не могу получить к нему доступ через точку.

Comment: ничего не понятно. приложите минимальный воспроизводимый код

Comment: У базового интерфейса ошибки нет ничего кроме метода [Error](https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go). Всё остальное вы добавляете туда [“следуя”](https://golangbot.com/custom-errors/) этому интерфейсу.

Answer (score 2):

В базовом интерфейсе `error` есть [только один метод](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error): `Error() string`

Никаких кодов ошибки в этом интерфейсе нет.

В дебагере вы видите конкретный тип ошибки, реализованный авторами той библиотеки, которой вы пользуетесь. Посмотрите, что это за тип, и потом приводите интерфейс `error` к этому типу. У приведённого значения поле `Code` будет видно, и компилятор вас не заругает.

```
    res, err := some_package.SomeFunc()
    if err != nil {
        concrete_err, ok := err.(some_package.SomeError)
        if ok {
            // Переменная concrete_err типа SomeError, у неё поле Code доступно
        } else {
            // не угадали тип ошибки, нужен план Б
        }
    }
```